# Помогите с Speech_Recognizer!

Tags: python, python-3.x, распознавание-речи

Решил написиать свою программу , что бы она считывала речь с микрофона и открывала калькулятор , ютуб или вк , но этого не происходит , что делать ?

```
from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
import webbrowser 
import pyttsx3
init()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("Что открыть - Калькулятор, Вконтакте или Ютуб ?")
engine.runAndWait()
print(Fore.GREEN)
x = input("Что открыть - Калькулятор(1), Вконтакте(2) или Ютуб(3) ?")
if x =="Калькулятор" or x =="калькулятор" or x ==" калькулятор" or x ==" Калькулятор" or x=="1":
    print(Fore.YELLOW)
    engine.say("Что будем делать ?")
    engine.runAndWait()
    f=input("Что будем делать ? (+,-,*,/,**)")
    if f == "+":
        print(Fore.BLUE)
        engine.say("Введите Первое число?")
        engine.runAndWait()
        a=int(input("Введите первое число:"))   
        engine.say("Введите Второе число?")
        engine.runAndWait()
        b=int(input("Введите второе число:"))
        c = a+b
        engine.say("Результат равен")
        engine.runAndWait()
        print("Результат : " + str(c))
    elif f == "-":
        engine.say("Введите Первое число?")
        engine.runAndWait()
        a=int(input("Введите первое число:"))   
        engine.say("Введите Второе число?")
        engine.runAndWait()
        b=int(input("Введите второе число:"))
        c = a-b
        engine.say("Результат равен")
        engine.runAndWait()
        print("Результат : " + str(c))
    elif f == "*":
        engine.say("Введите Первое число?")
        engine.runAndWait()
        a=int(input("Введите первое число:"))   
        engine.say("Введите Второе число?")
        engine.runAndWait()
        b=int(input("Введите второе число:"))
        c = a*b
        engine.say("Результат равен")
        engine.runAndWait()
        print("Результат : " + str(c))
    elif f == "/":
        engine.say("Введите Первое число?")
        engine.runAndWait()
        a=int(input("Введите первое число:"))   
        engine.say("Введите Второе число?")
        engine.runAndWait()
        b=int(input("Введите второе число:"))
        c = a/b
        engine.say("Результат равен")
        engine.runAndWait()
        print("Результат : " + str(c))
    elif f == "**":
        engine.say("Введите Первое число?")
        engine.runAndWait()
        a=int(input("Введите первое число:"))   
        engine.say("Введите Второе число?")
        engine.runAndWait()
        b=int(input("Введите второе число:"))
        c = a**b
        engine.say("Результат равен")
        engine.runAndWait()
        print("Результат : " + str(c))
    else:
        print(Fore.MAGENTA)
        print("Ошибка!")

if x =="Ютуб" or x =="ютуб" or x =="ЮТУБ" or x =="youtube" or x =="Youtube" or x =="YOUTUBE" or x ==" ютуб" or x=="3" or x ==" Ютуб" or x ==" Ютуб" or x ==" ЮТУБ" or x ==" youtube" or x ==" YOUTUBE" or x =="ютубчик" or x ==".ne," or x ==".NE,":
    webbrowser.get("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s").open("http://youtube.com") 

if x =="Вконтакте" or x == "Vk" or x == "vk" or x == " Vk" or x == " vk" or x=="вк" or x==" вк" or x=="Вк" or x=="2" or x==" Вк":
    webbrowser.get("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s").open("http://vk.com") 
input("Для выхода нажмите Enter.")
```

Comment: У вас Windows? Покажите весь стёк ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать и лучше, но и так сойдет. Сразу учись комментировать, потом легче будет. С цветами сам 
Ты забыл скобки поставить

Пример: if (x = "...") or (x = "...")

Еще там ошибки, можешь посмотреть в коде моем, как более-менее правильно

```
from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
import webbrowser 
import pyttsx3

#функции
def speak( what ):
    engine.say( what )
    engine.runAndWait()
    engine.stop()

def functions(x):
    try:
    #открываем калькулятор
        if (x == "калькулятор") or (x == "1"):

        #Выбор действия
            speak("Что будем делать?")
            f = input("Что будем делать? (+,-,*,/,**): ")

        #Производим суммирование
            if f == "+":

                #Узнаем первое число
                speak("Введите Первое число")
                a = input(+ "Введите первое число: ")
                a = float(a)   

                #Узнаем второе число
                speak("Введите Второе число")
                b = input("Введите второе число: ")
                b = float(b)

                #Производим суммирование
                c = a + b
                c = str(c)

                #Выводим результат
                speak("Результат: " + c)
                print("Результат: " + str(c))
                input("Нажмите Enter чтобы выйти")

        #Производим вычитание
            elif f == "-":

                #Узнаем первое число
                speak("Введите Первое число")
                a = input("Введите первое число: ")  

                #Узнаем второе число
                speak("Введите Второе число")
                b = input("Введите второе число: ")

                #Производим вычитание
                c = a - b
                c = str(c)

                #Выводим результат
                speak("Результат: " + c)
                print("Результат: " + c)
                input("Нажмите Enter чтобы выйти")

        #Производим умножение
            elif f == "*":

                #Узнаем первое число
                speak("Введите Первое число")
                a = input("Введите первое число: ")
                a = float(a)   

                #Узнаем второе число
                speak("Введите Второе число")
                b = input("Введите второе число: ")
                b = float(b)

                #Производим умножение
                c = a * b
                c = str(c)

                #Выводим результат
                speak("Результат: " + c)
                print("Результат: " + c)
                input("Нажмите Enter чтобы выйти")

            #Производим деление
            elif f == "/":

                #Узнаем первое число
                speak("Введите Первое число")
                a = input("Введите первое число: ")
                a = float(a)   

                #Узнаем второе число
                speak("Введите Второе число")
                b = input("Введите второе число: ")
                b = float(b)

                #Производим деление
                c = a / b
                c = str(c)

                #Выводим результат
                speak("Результат: " + c)
                print("Результат: " + c)
                input("Нажмите Enter чтобы выйти")

        #Возводим в степень
            elif f == "**":

                #Узнаем первое число
                speak("Введите Первое число")
                a = input("Введите первое число: ")
                a = float(a)   

                #Узнаем второе число
                speak("Введите Второе число")
                b = input("Введите второе число (степень): ")
                b = float(b)

                #Узнаем результат
                c = a ** b
                c = str(c)

                #Выводим результат
                speak("Результат: " + c)
                print("Результат: " + c)
                input("Нажмите Enter чтобы выйти")

            else:
                print("Ошибка!")

        #открываем вк
        elif (x == "вк") or (x == "вконтакте") or (x == "2"):
            webbrowser.open("https://vk.com") 

        #открываем ютуб
        elif  (x == "ют") or (x == "ютуб") or (x == "you tube") or (x == "youtube") or (x == "3"):
            webbrowser.open("https://youtube.com") 

        #Действие не опознано
        else:
            speak("Неизвестное действие")

    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        speak("неожиданная ошибка")
        print ("Неожиданная ошибка...")

#запуск
engine = pyttsx3.init()
init()

speak("Что открыть - Калькулятор, Вконтакте или Ютуб ?")
x = input("Что открыть - калькулятор (1), вконтакте (2) или ютуб (3)? ")
x = x.lower()

functions(x)
```

Comment: Тут скобки не нужны: `if (x == "калькулятор") or (x == "1"):` - у операций сравнения более высокий приоритет чем у логических операций.